# How can I compare with '>'

Tags: java

I am working on a program using package for the FTC robotics tournament. My issue is with

`import com.qualcomm.robotcore.util.ElapsedTime;`

The variable `runtime` does not compare with an int as it is a Type `ElapsedTime`.
I have tried just about every thing I could find and it either results in a compile or runtime error. How can I do: `if (runtime > 10) {`?

Comment: A quick look at the documentation shows different methods for retrieving the time elapsed in long/double, use those methods to fetch the value and then compare them.
https://ftctechnh.github.io/ftc_app/doc/javadoc/com/qualcomm/robotcore/util/ElapsedTime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on this class shows quite a number of fields.

https://ftctechnh.github.io/ftc_app/doc/javadoc/com/qualcomm/robotcore/util/ElapsedTime.html

While the following code snippet should compile (and run), it may not be correct for what you are using it for. *(For instance, do you care about nanosecond precision? Or are seconds good enough?)*

```
    if (10 < runtime.time())
    {
        System.out.println("`runtime.time()` is greater than 10");
    }
```

Comment: Seconds are good enough, although milliseconds would be better. Nanoseconds are not needed for my uses.